# Groups with prescribed Ulm invariants

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, abelian-groups

In Kaplansky's book infinite abelian groups he provides (through some exercises) a complete classification of $p^{\infty}$-torsion countable abelian groups in terms of Ulm invariants. In other words such a group is entirely determined by its vector of Ulm invariants and one case describe precisely which vectors are attained. Kaplansky states "the question of existence deserves investigation….  In the uncountable case not much is known, but in exercise 44 we indicate that further conditions have to be imposed".

**Question:** Has this problem been successively addressed? Do we now know which lists of Ulm invariants are attainable without restriction on the cardinality?

I am also curious about the uniqueness side, i.e. to know, to what extent people have pushed our understanding of $p^{\infty}$-torsion abelian groups beyond the countable case (i.e. is there some kind of generalization of Ulm's theorem beyond the countable setting?).

Any reference would be highly appreciated!

Comment: It's Kaplansk**y**

Comment: Fixed, thank you

Comment: MathJax note: please use **double stars** `**double stars**`, not $\textbf{TeX trickery}$ `$\textbf{TeX trickery}$`, for boldface text.  I have edited accordingly.